# Как в postgres конвертировать дату с формата unixtimestamp в timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, unixtimestamp

Есть задача: в уже имеющейся таблице изменить формат даты. В исходнике формат unixtimestamp (это вот примерно вот это: 1617200366, т.е это отсчет в секундах с даты 1970-01-01). В базе (postgres) строк много, как перевести в формат timestamp YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
melkij=> select to_timestamp(1617200366);
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2021-03-31 17:19:26+03
```

Есть штатная функция `to_timestamp`